# Changing Italics in references to plain text in natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, italic

I'm currently updating my manuscript following the instructions of the journal. A point I'm currently stuck at is to update the book titles as non-italics. I searched for any potential solution on the web, but I have yet to find one. The solutions I found are for the builtin bibliography and not for the `unsrtnat` bibliography style.

**Current references item**

[image: sample-ref]

I want to make the booktitle "Neural computation" appear non-italics. I'm using natbib (unsrtnat). Is there a way to do it someway ?

**EDIT**

My current work-around way of achieving what I want is to redefine `\emph` s.t it outputs `\text`. If you do this, make sure you DO NOT use `\emph` in your manuscript, instead use `\textit`.

```
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\text{#1}}
```

Comment: I'm curious, what exactly do you think the `text` command is supposed to be used for?

Comment: Note that the formatting via `bibtex` styles are hardwired and this cannot easily be changed, other than making a copy of the style (here `unsrtnat.bst`), save it under a new name (important), and then edit the `bst` file. You get much more flexibility using `biblatex`.

Comment: @daleif - If the suppression of italics is meant to be applied to all fields in all entry types, the remedy is actually fairly simple, even with BibTeX and the `unsrtnat` bib style. Please see the answer I just posted for a possible solution.

Comment: @Mico you're answer is exactly what I was referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to suppress *all* italics in the bibliography, and not just for book titles (or, possibly, names of journals), I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Find the file `unsrtnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `unsrtnat-noitalics.bst`. (Don't modify a file in the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `unsrtnat-noitalics.bst` in a text editor. (The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.)
- In the file `unsrtnat-noitalics.bst`, locate the function `emphasize`. In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 207. It should look like this:

  ```
  FUNCTION {emphasize}
  { duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ "" }
      { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
    if$
  }
  ```
- Replace this function with the following "stub" of a function:

  ```
  FUNCTION {emphasize}
  {}
  ```

  If you're guessing that the modified form of this function does nothing to its input, i.e., passes any input straight to output, you'd be correct.
- Save the file `unsrtnat-noitalics.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. If you have no idea what the instruction in the preceding sentence means, I recommend that you select the former option.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-noitalics}` and perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!